# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker Disabled Days of the Week error value

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

If use daysOfWeekDisabled in a input with a previous value, the input value is reset to the first day of the year.

For example I have a input text with value = '01/07/2016' and after do:

```
$('#myinput').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'es',
    format: 'L',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5],
  });
```

The value is set to '02/01/2016' if don't use daysOfWeekDisabled it maintain the value. It shouldn't be change the value.

Comment: Can you replicate this issue in a fiddle?

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/hrv2h2rb/ the input value is "02/07/2016"

Comment: I have the same problem ( http://jsfiddle.net/supersonique/3tpro70q/2/ ) and not found the solution too.  The daysOfWeekDisabled option change the input date and not read current date set as input's value.